# How to fix Sequelize nested includes not working with limit/order/attributes?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got some models that have associations with each other, and I need to grab them all in a certain request. I need to use `limit`, `order`, and `attributes` on basically all parts of it, but this is causing the nested includes to freak out and I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with it.

It doesn't really print any errors or anything, the models either just don't get included in the response (i.e they are empty.), or they get included but stuff like order/limit is ignored.

I've already tried using `subQuery`, `separate`, etc... None of those worked.

The query in question;

```
const categories = await models.Category.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'title', 'description'],
  order: [['title', 'ASC']],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Product,
      attributes: ['id', 'title'],
      through: { attributes: [] },
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Price,
          attributes: ['id', 'amount', 'createdAt'],
          order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
          limit: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

The associations;

```
models.Category.belongsToMany(models.Product);
models.Product.belongsToMany(models.Category);

models.Product.hasMany(models.Price);
models.Price.belongsTo(models.Product);
```

I ideally want the query provided above to return;

- `Category` with the order of Ascending based on `title`.
- `Product` inside of `Category` with the attributes `id` and `title`.
- `Price` inside of `Product` with the attributes `id`, `amount`, and `createdAt`, the order of Descending based on `createdAt`, and with a limit of 1.

Comment: Can you add the raw query in your question?

Comment: @NimishGupta I think I can? But on what part? All of them or just the ones I need ordered? My only issue with using raw is that is sort of screws up the json format sometimes.

Comment: Can you explain why this is included `through: { attributes: [] }` in the `Product` includes? As for the `belongsToMany` associations, according to the documentation the `through` is missing "Defining through is required. Sequelize would previously attempt to autogenerate names but that would not always lead to the most logical setups." http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations

Comment: `order`, and i guess `limit` as well are attribute of the `findAll` parameters, so you need to move `order` and `limit` to outside of `include`. Check here.  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4553

Comment: as @Emma says, you need to move the `order` and `limit` at the same level of include. [Here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#ordering) is the actual Ordering documentation

Answer (score 6):

In order to get the query to sort by `Product.Price.createdAt`, add `[models.Product, models.Price, 'createdAt', 'DESC']` to `order`. As far as limiting: in order to limit the included model, you need to run it as a separate query, so add `separate: true` to the include.

Code:

```
const categories = await models.Category.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'title', 'description'],
  order: [['title', 'ASC'], [models.Product, models.Price, 'createdAt', 'DESC']],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Product,
      attributes: ['id', 'title'],
      through: { attributes: [] },
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Price,
          attributes: ['id', 'amount', 'createdAt'],
          separate: true,
          limit: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```